# How to pass C++ Struct To C# DLL?

Tags: c#, c++, struct, pinvoke, marshalling

I've a C# DLL below like. I want to use this C# DLL in C++ Builder.

But I don't know C# Struct and C++ Struct marshalling:

```
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace TestLibrary
{

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public struct MyStruct
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;
    }


    public class Class1
    {
        [DllExport("DoSomething", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static int DoSomething(int x, int y, ref MyStruct myStruct)
        {
            myStruct.X = 50;
            myStruct.Y = 75;
            return x + y;
        }

    }
}
```

I want to pass "myStruct" parameter from C++ Builder below like.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
  struct MyStruct
  {
    int X;
    int Y;
   };

  int (__stdcall *DoSomething)(int,int,MyStruct);


  HINSTANCE dllHandle = NULL;
  dllHandle = LoadLibrary( edtdllPath->Text.c_str());
  if(dllHandle == NULL) return;
  int status = -1;

  try
  {
    DoSomething =(int (__stdcall *)(int,int,MyStruct)) GetProcAddress(dllHandle, "DoSomething");
  }
  catch(Exception &Err)
  {
    ShowMessage(Err.Message);
  }

  if(DoSomething != NULL)
  {
    try
    {
      MyStruct myStruct;
      status = DoSomething(5,5,myStruct);
      String strStatus = status;

      ShowMessage(strStatus);
      ShowMessage(myStruct.X);
      ShowMessage(myStruct.Y);
    }
    catch(EAccessViolation &err)
    {
     ShowMessage(err.Message);
    }
  }

}
```

When I debug code,myStruct.X and myStruct.Y value is wrong.

Where is my wrong ?

Comment: The string is a big problem. You can't use `ref StringBuilder`, and I don't think you can use `StringBuilder`. By far the easiest solution is to use `UnmanagedType.BStr` and use the COM `BStr`. You do need to back up a little and understand the basics more than you currently do.

Comment: thanks for interest @DavidHeffernan.
I've checked StringBuilder parameter.it's working.
Not worked only myStruct parameter.

Comment: No, the string builder can't be working. Ask yourself who's going to deallocate the memory? For starters. There are more problems.  You are mistaken.

Comment: thanks @DavidHeffernan ur guru

Comment: I've added adress to X like that.
  struct MyStruct
  {
    int *X;
    double *Y;
  };

I get value of "myStruct.X" as true below like.
ShowMessage(*myStruct.X);

But value of *myStruct.X wrong.

Comment: Why would you do that? The C# has `int` rather than pointer to `int`. I think you are quite deeply confused here. I think you need to step back and solve one problem at a time. Mixing the struct errors with the string errors is going to be confusing. The question is too messy as it stands for me to be prepared to write an answer.

Comment: I want using, c#  struct or  class in c++ builder as basically.

Comment: And what about the string?

Comment: I've modified my question.
I've removed string parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# project declares the struct parameter like this:

```
ref MyStruct myStruct
```

That marshals as a pointer to the struct. In C++ that means

```
MyStruct*
```

So change the declaration of the function pointer variable to be like so:

```
int (__stdcall *DoSomething)(int,int,MyStruct*);
```

And use the same type when you cast:

```
DoSomething =(int (__stdcall *)(int,int,MyStruct*)) GetProcAddress(dllHandle, "DoSomething");
```

Note that a typedef would serve you better here to avoid repeating yourself. And note also that `GetProcAddress` does not raise exceptions. It signals errors by returning `NULL`. You don't check for errors properly.

When you call the function pass the address of the struct:

```
status = DoSomething(5,5,&myStruct);
```

It's also a little pointless to declare `status` and initialise it to -1, but then overwrite that value later. It would be more idiomatic to declare and initialise it like this:

```
int status = DoSomething(5,5,&myStruct);
```

Comment: I get error that line status = DoSomething(5,5,&myStruct);

[C++ Error] Unit1.cpp(63): E2034 Cannot convert 'MyStruct * *' to 'MyStruct *'

But when I removed that & character compiled.

Thank you for everything @David

Comment: That's because you've changed the code from that in the question. You declared `MyStruct *myStruct` which is a mistake.

Comment: When I add more than 2 fields to struct then throwing EAccessViolation exception.
What's can be source of problem ? 
How can I debug this problem ?


**---------------------------
Debugger Exception Notification
---------------------------
Project Project1.exe raised exception class EAccessViolation with message 'Access violation at address CCCCCCCD. Read of address CCCCCCCD'. Process stopped. Use Step or Run to continue.
---------------------------
OK   Help   
---------------------------**

Comment: You're rigth.
I have add only int Z named field like that. 

 struct MyStruct
  {
    int X;
    double Y;
    int Z;
 };

Comment: That's only half of the code. The C# code matters too. For some reason you packed the C# struct, but not the C++ struct. Packing is not recommended. It results in misalignment of the data. Why did you decide to pack?

Comment: Yes You're rigth. I removed "Pack" from c# struct.it working well now.
I'll look string fields now.

Comment: I've a other question that nested struct marshal.
Can I ask you here?

Answer (score 3):

You are not passing your struct as pointer to c#, yet in c# you told that it would be a pointer (`ref`).