# Using C# Nested Structs In C++

Tags: c#, c++, struct, pinvoke, marshalling

I've asked before that question.

[How to pass C++ Struct To C# DLL ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32502499/how-to-pass-c-struct-to-c-sharp-dll)

Now I'm trying to nested struct marshal.

I've replaced structs like that.

```
typedef struct TKeyValue
{
  char Key[15];
  char Value[15];
} TKeyValue;

typedef struct MyStruct
{
  TKeyValue *KeyValues[1];
} TMyStruct;
typedef int (__stdcall *DoSomething)(char [],char[],TMyStruct *);
```

calling DLL function

```
void __fastcall TForm1::btnInvokeMethodClick(TObject *Sender)
{
  wchar_t buf[256];
  String DLL_FILENAME = "ClassLibrary1.dll";
  HINSTANCE dllHandle = NULL;

  dllHandle = LoadLibrary(DLL_FILENAME.c_str());

  FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, GetLastError(),MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), buf, 256, NULL);
  OutputDebugStringW(buf);

  if(dllHandle == NULL) return;

  DoSomething xDoSomething = (DoSomething)GetProcAddress(dllHandle, "DoSomething");
  FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, GetLastError(),MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), buf, 256, NULL);
  OutputDebugStringW(buf);

  if (xDoSomething == NULL) return;

  try
  {
      TMyStruct aMyStruct;

      char parameter1[15];
      char parameter2[15];
      strcpy(parameter1,"value1");
      strcpy(parameter2,"value2");

      int result = xDoSomething(parameter1,parameter2,&aMyStruct);

      FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, GetLastError(),MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), buf, 256, NULL);
      OutputDebugStringW(buf);

      //access violation at this line
      ShowMessage(aMyStruct.KeyValue[0]->Key);
  }
  catch(EAccessViolation &err)
  {
    ShowMessage(err.Message);
  }

  FreeLibrary(dllHandle);
```

C# Side

```
    [StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct KeyValue
    {
        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 15)]
        public string Key;

        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 15)]
        public string Value;
    }



    [ComVisible(true)]
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct MyStruct
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1)]
        public KeyValue[] KeyValues;
    }

        [DllExport("DoSomething", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static int DoSomething(string tcKnVkn, string sifre, ref MyStruct myStruct)
    {
        try
        {
            MyStruct.KeyValues[0].Key = "key 1";
            MyStruct.KeyValues[0].Value = "value 1";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }

        return 2;
    }
```

When i compile my project and run, it throws access violation error after accessing Key field of TKeyValue like that `aMyStruct.KeyValue[0]->Key`

What's my mistaken ?

Thanks.

Comment: Remove everything other than the nested struct. Make sure that works. Then add the nested array of struct. Check that works. And so on. This is the very essence of debugging. First isolate the problem.

Comment: `myStruct.KeyValues = new KeyValue[2]` looks odd though. Doesn't the marshaller allocate that? Anyway, I won't look further until you cut this down and isolate the problem and show complete code on both sides, a [mcve].

Comment: I've modified my question

Comment: Well, on the C++ side you have an array of pointers to struct, on the C# side an array of struct.

Comment: I'll try debug later.I'm confused. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your `Arrays` field. The C++ declaration is:

```
char *Array[3];           // 3 pointers, uses up 12 bytes (32bit system)
```

Which means an array of 3 pointers. Stop for a second and consider how far off that is from a string -- it's not a contiguous block of memory with characters that you're passing, you're passing a *number*. If you wanted to pass 3 C strings, you'd declare it like this instead (not what you're sending by the way, you need different attributes on the C# side):

```
char Array[15][3];        // 3 strings, uses up 45 bytes
```

You're sending garbage in those pointers, and when the C code is trying to dereference them it gets an access violation.

Comment: He isn't declaring that field as a string. He declared it as `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
        public string[] Array;`

Comment: Right, and what's inside that array?

Comment: Default marshalling for `string` is `const char*`